# React router open route in new window

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to open a route in a new window upon a hyperlink click. `target=_blank` is not of much help since I am trying to open in new window, not new tab. `window.open` also opens in a new tab. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Ok, I got window.open working but I am still not sure how I can open a new route in that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this to open a new window:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
```

If you have different urls (dev env, test env, prod env) you can use this to get the base url:

```
window.location.origin
```

So final code is:

```
window.open(window.location.origin + "/ROUTE_U_WANT", '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
```

Comment: Thanks Paolo but this did not work. It opens a new window with the URL to the correct route all right but shows the same content as the original page where the link is

Comment: Hi, let me know if this example is what you want: 

`class Hello extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
    
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  onClick(){
   window.open(window.location.origin + "/foreyez/vdk7guob/show", '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<div>
      Hi
      <button onClick = {this.onClick}>Open new Window and new route</button>
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
`

Are you sure that your app routing works?

Comment: Hi have tested this code in JSFiddle with React. You can paste it inside the js content [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)

Comment: Thanks so much! adding a # as in window.open(window.location.origin + "#/newRoute",'_blank','toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0'); worked for some reason.

Comment: I think that is "how" you have implemented the routing that determines how you have to build the URL :)